# PHP mailer SMTP - Não funciona

Tags: phpmailer, smtp

O código que eu tenho é o seguinte:

```
require_once ( 'class.phpmailer.php' );
$Mail = new PHPMailer();

$Mail->IsSMTP(); 
$Mail->Host        = ""; // O QUE COLOCAR AQUI??
$Mail->SMTPDebug   = 0; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
$Mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; 
$Mail->SMTPSecure  = "ssl"; 
$Mail->Port        = 465; 
$Mail->Username    = 'meuemail@gmail.com'; 
$Mail->Password    = 'minhapass'; 
$Mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From        = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
$Mail->AddAdress    = ('meuemail@gmail.com'); 
$Mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line
$Mail->isHTML( TRUE );
$Mail->SMTPDebug   = 1;

$Mail->Body  = "corpo";
$Mail->AddAddress("meuemail@gmail.com"); // To: 
$Mail->Send();
```

Obrigada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falta indicar qual o host que irá enviar a mensagem, penso que para o Gmail é "smtp.gmail.com":

```
$Mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Se não funcionar, ative o modo debug:

```
$Mail->SMTPDebug   = 1;
```

Troque também a última linha:

```
$Mail->Send();
```

Por esse código:

```
if(!$Mail->Send()) { 
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $Mail->ErrorInfo; 
} else { 
    echo "Enviado com sucesso!"; 
}
```

Altere a sua pergunta e posta o erro que é retornado, assim teremos mais informações.

Comment: Obrigada @Filipe Moraes já esteve a funcionar. Mas agora está a dar erro.

Comment: @Claudia o erro diz que a senha não está correta. Você alterou a senha do e-mail? Se sim tem que alterar no código também.

Comment: eu não alterei a senha do email.

Comment: Agora está-me a dar um erro diferente..já atualizei a pergunta

Comment: @Claudia altere a sua pergunta e coloque o código PHP que você está a usar no momento, pelo que vejo o atual está descontextualizado.

Comment: o código da pergunta já está actualizado. Obrigada

Comment: já resolvi o meu problema. Obrigada

Comment: @Claudia que ótimo! O problema agora é que a resposta ficou descontextualizada. Olhando para pergunta e para a resposta, não vai resolver o problema de quem obteve o mesmo erro. Qual foi a solução que você encontrou? Se foi algo específico, pelo menos volte a colocar a pergunta no seu estado inicial.

Comment: tem razão! Já coloquei a pergunta no estado inicial.